# Error Indicator Light on Heater

Tags: current, switches, light, heater

[image: Diagram]

I have a heater with a neon bulb wired in parallel with a safety cutoff switch. The full current of the heater goes through the safety switch. If the switch trips, wouldn’t the full current just go through the bulb, very briefly, and burn the bulb out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the bulb has a much higher resistance than the heater, limiting the current to a few mA.

Comment: Oh! Gotcha, so the heater coil is almost like a piece of wire and it’s just lighting the bulb!  Thank you this had me stumped for a while.